# Google maps API error: "stringwithcontentsofurl is deprecated"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-maps, development-environment

I have code that keeps giving me an "stringwithcontentsofurl is deprecated" error and I can't figure out how to fix it. The app keeps taking me to google maps and showing the center of the ocean at 0.0 lat, 0.0 long. This is the code I have now...

```
NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
NSLog(@"locationstr:%@",locationStr);
NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double lat = 0.0;
double lon = 0.0;

if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    lat = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    lon = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Address, %@ not found: Error %@",addressStr, [items objectAtIndex:0]);
}
NSLog(@"latlonislatlon:%.12f,%.12f,urlstr:%@",lat,lon,urlStr);
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = lat;
location.longitude = lon;
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you not read the documentation? If you look up that method, it will tell you what the replacement is.

Comment: @rdelmar wow, way to be rude. i'm simply asking for help. no one said you had to answer. you could've read this and moved on. "if you don't have anything nice to say, don't say anything at all" have a great day

Comment: The point is, you should do your research first before asking for help.

Comment: and my point is that you didn't need to say anything. again, you could've read this and moved on. plenty of other people answered and actually tried to help. good day

Answer (score 0):

It has been replaced with

```
stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
```

or

```
stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your variables have been set to 0.0 for latitude and longitude.

Comment: that's what they were set to previously and it was working. what should it be set to?

Comment: @user2706002 I don't know what you should set them to. I just answered your question though. Your question was why it shows coordinates 0,0. I answered that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove deprecation warning

```
NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding error:nil];
```

Also try using different lat, long since their might be problem with your lat long